# Android Search View Filter

Tags: android, search, layout, filter

I have an Android app with a Main Menu filled with buttons. In the Action bar corresponding to this view I have a Search Button configured to use with the Search View widget. 
For this to work I have another class that is the searchable one that makes the hard work and has a List View with all the products that my database has.

What I'd like to do, and I don't know how, is that when the user is in the Main Menu and presses the search button, nothing changes until it introduces some letter. When he does, it should start show the filtered products list, just like WhatsApp app does with the contacts and conversations. This should be done "on top" of the buttons that my Main Menu already has, because if I change to another Activity then the Search view widget will close.

What am I thinking wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Check this code out:

https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/ActionBar/SearchView

- If I understand you, this is what you do currently:

https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Search/Lorem

He does "Query-style search" but you can also do "Filter-style search" mentioned at page 2521 in the book from Marc Murphy. But this is not described. So far I'm using the first github example.

- This is also a nice example that expand on Lorem with automatic suggestions. Only work for Activity and not Fragment (also found in SDK samples/android-14):

https://github.com/android/platform_development/tree/master/samples/SearchableDictionary